# Creating an ImmutableList of a type that is unknown at compile-time

Tags: c#, .net, immutability, .net-core, immutable-collections

Given a `Collection<T>` whose type `T` is only known in runtime (not at compile time), I would like to generate an `ImmutableList<T>`.

The method I would like to create may like like:

```
var immutableList = CreateImmutableList(originalList, type);
```

where originalList is `IEnumerable` and type is the `T` of of the generated `ImmutableList<T>`.

How?!

(I'm working with NET .Core)

EDIT: Thanks to the comments I have found a working solution. It uses AddRange method.

```
namespace Sample.Tests
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Immutable;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Reflection;
    using Xunit;

    public class ImmutabilityTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public void CollectionCanBeConvertedToImmutable()
        {
            var original = new Collection<object>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, };
            var result = original.AsImmutable(typeof(int));

            Assert.NotEmpty(result);
            Assert.IsAssignableFrom<ImmutableList<int>>(result);
        }
    }

    public static class ReflectionExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable AsImmutable(this IEnumerable collection, Type elementType)
        {
            var immutableType = typeof(ImmutableList<>).MakeGenericType(elementType);
            var addRangeMethod = immutableType.GetMethod("AddRange");
            var typedCollection = ToTyped(collection, elementType);

            var emptyImmutableList = immutableType.GetField("Empty").GetValue(null);
            emptyImmutableList = addRangeMethod.Invoke(emptyImmutableList, new[] { typedCollection });
            return (IEnumerable)emptyImmutableList;
        }

        private static object ToTyped(IEnumerable original, Type type)
        {
            var method = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Cast", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).MakeGenericMethod(type);
            return method.Invoke(original, new object[] { original });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This won´t work. Either you know the type at compile-time which makes it easy to create a `Collection<MyType>`, or you don´t know the type in which case you can´t expect the compiler to guess what you provide it at runtime.

Comment: `CreateImmutableList` would have to return an `object`, since it can't return `ImmutableList<T>` (since, after all, we don't *know* `T`). Is that what you want? In that case, be explicit about what type the `var` is supposed to be.

Comment: Is `originalList` also a `IEnumerable<T>` at runtime?

Comment: Also, are you talking about `System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableList<T>`?

Comment: Yes! That! ImmutableList<T>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using reflection:

1. Create the right `Type` object for `ImmutableList<T>`
2. Fill it with data
3. Return it

Here is a [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program that demonstrates. I'm assuming that by "immutable list" you mean `System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableList<T>` available through Nuget:

```
void Main()
{
    object il = CreateImmutableList(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, typeof(int));
    il.GetType().Dump();
    il.Dump();
}

public static object CreateImmutableList(IEnumerable collection, Type elementType)
{
    // TODO: guard clauses for parameters == null
    var resultType = typeof(ImmutableList<>).MakeGenericType(elementType);
    var result = resultType.GetField("Empty").GetValue(null);
    var add = resultType.GetMethod("Add");
    foreach (var element in collection)
        result = add.Invoke(result, new object[] { element });
    return result;
}
```

Output:

```
System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableList`1[System.Int32]

1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Cool! But it doesn't work when collection is of type ArrayList or Collection<T>

Comment: It works with `Collection<T>`,  but not ArrayList because ArrayList is not generic. Why on earth are you using ArrayList anyway?

Comment: Edited to support `IEnumerable` (without `<T>`), which would handle `ArrayList`. Since I tested with `Collection<T>` and it works you would need to tell me what you tested.

Comment: Nice, but we lost even more performance removing the AddRange call :(

Comment: Please, take a look at my edited question (uses AddRange). I would like you to review it!

Answer (score 0):

If you are ready for boxing/ unboxing, then you can do something like this

```
           var objectCollection = new Collection<object>();
            objectCollection.Add(3);
            objectCollection.Add(4);
            var immutableList = objectCollection.ToImmutableList();
```

Here element type is `int`, and we add values to a collection of object. If we want to get back the typed values, we can do:

```
    foreach (var obj in immutableList)
                {
                    int myVal = (int) Convert.ChangeType(obj, typeof(int));
                    Console.WriteLine(myVal);
                }
```

**NOTE:** It may have performance impacts if your list is big and element type is a value type owning to boxing/unboxing

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CreateRange`. To minimize reflection, use a helper method:

```
private static ImmutableList<T> CreateImmutableList<T>(IEnumerable<object> source)
  => ImmutableList.CreateRange(source.Cast<T>());

private MethodInfo _createImmutableList = typeof(ReflectionExtensions)
  .GetMethod(nameof(CreateImmutableList), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

// then: 
return _createImmutableList 
  .MakeGenericMethod(elementType)
  .Invoke(null, new object [] { collection });
```